# Compiler warning for mixed array and polymorphism

Tags: c++, arrays, polymorphism

In More Effective C++, an interesting point brought up is that mixing array's and polymorphism is a bad idea. For eg:

```
class Base {
    public:
    Base(int y) : a(y) {}
    int a;
};

class D : public Base {
    public:
    D(int w, int y) : Base(y), c(w) {}
    int c;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Base &obj )
{
    os << obj.a << std::endl;
    return os;
}

// This function will work perfectly well if i pass in a `Base` array, 
// but if i pass in `D` array we are going to run into some problems. 
// Namely that `arr[i+1] = &arr[i] + sizeof(Base)` will not progress 
// the array correctly for a `D` array.
void printArray(const Base arr[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << arr[i];
    }
}

int main() {
   D arr[5] = { D(0, 10), D(1, 11), D(2, 12), D(3, 13), D(4, 14)};
   printArray(arr); // This compiles without complaint! I understand that the
                    // conversion is legal, but it seems like a warning
                    // about this would be a good idea. 
}
```

*Note:* I know this is bad design but is to illustrate a point.

The problem here is that when mixing these two in the way i have above, when we iterate through the array to print we will not progress the element of the array by the correct amount (ie we move by `sizeof(Base)` instead of `sizeof(D)`). This results in the output:

```
10
0
11
1
12
```

[[Live example.]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d4b198328fd0a8d)

(And i am guessing that calling the `operator<<` like this is probably UB).

When compiling with `g++ -std=c++1y -Wall -Weffc++ -pedantic main.cpp` I get no warnings or errors.

1. **Is there a compiler flag that I can  enable that indicates a warning in this scenario?**
2. **If not, why not?**

Comment: Well, the answer to `2)` is that "warnings" are not mandatory for a compiler to implement.  You can ask the implementors of g++ to add such a warning (if it doesn't exist already), but they are not compelled to do so by any standard.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, true, but GCC goes above and beyond with their warnings, i am wondering if there is a technical difficulty in detecting this?

Comment: You have to ask the engineers that put together the compiler.  There answer could be anywhere from "that's a good idea" to "we don't have time" to "it already exists".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well i hope it's 3.

Comment: You better not use C style array in this case. The fact you hardcore array size shows ugliness of this code already. If you use proper C++ code you would not have such issue.

Comment: @Slava, Yep, i know, hence the `Note: I know this is bad design but is to illustrate a point.` I am just interested in if there is a compiler warning about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A compiler could do a lot of static analyzing, and could know that the pointer `arr` in the function is used as an array with unexpected results.

However, doing that is slow and uses a lot (more) of memory, and programmers are generally impatient and want their compilations to be done as quick as possible using as little other resources as possible too. Therefore most compilers only do static analyzes that are relatively quick and easy, leaving the hard work to dedicated static analyzers.

Comment: So i assume you think the answer to 1) is no.

Comment: @Ben Probably no. If the documentation doesn't mention any such warning, then the only way to know for sure is get the source (if it's available) and read it. :)

Comment: I dont really buy the argument of slowing down the compilation, as warnings usually can be turned off. So anybody who is concerned about safety could turn them on and everybody concerned about compilation speed can leave them off

Comment: @tobi303 You generally still want warnings, even when building projects with tens of thousand of files (where a comprehensive static analysis like done by dedicated linters could mean a moderately long coffee-break).

Answer (score 1):

`void printArray(const Base arr[])` is equivalent to `void printArray(const Base* arr)`.

It's legal to pass a pointer of type `D` to a function whose parameter is of type `const Base*`. So the compiler won't give any warnings.

Comment: Compilers are allowed to give warnings for legal constructs.

Comment: I know that it is legal behaviour, so is `int arr[5]; arr[6] = 10`, we get a warning for that though.

Comment: @Ben Suppose `printArray` is defined in a third library, and there's no function call to pass a pointer of type `D` to `printArray` in that library.  The compiler won't complain anything. However, when someone uses the library, and passes a pointer of type `D` to `printArray`. I don't think it's a good idea for the compiler to check the implementation of `printArary` in the third library, to see if `printArray` requires an array of type `Base`.

Comment: He's asking about *array decay* to a pointer of the base class, not a warning for pointers of `Derived` getting passed to functions that take pointers to `Base`. Once the array has decayed into a pointer, the static information that there's more than one element is gone, but if you'll notice, he's asking about a scenario where the compiler can decisively know the argument is a decayed array of type Derived, and know that the signature *as declared*  indicates an array of type `Base`.

Comment: Since compilers have proven time and again to be capable of relatively complex static analysis when it comes to issuing warnings, he wants to know why *this* static analysis isn't happening.

Comment: @jaggedSpire Exactly.

Answer (score -1):

FYI, mixing arrays and polymorphism can be done if the polymorphism is provided as an implementation detail of a handle class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// a handle which will happily own any class which implements the concept
struct Thing
{
    struct concept
    {
        virtual void sayHello() const = 0;
        virtual ~concept() = default;
    };

    Thing(std::unique_ptr<concept> ptr) : _impl(std::move(ptr)) {}

    void sayHello() const { _impl->sayHello(); }

    std::unique_ptr<concept> _impl;
};

struct thing_a : Thing::concept
{
    void sayHello() const override { std::cout << "hello from A\n"; }
};

struct thing_b : Thing::concept
{
    void sayHello() const override { std::cout << "hello from B\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Thing> things;

    things.emplace_back(std::make_unique<thing_a>());
    things.emplace_back(std::make_unique<thing_b>());

    for (const auto& t : things) { t.sayHello(); }
}
```

expected output:

```
hello from A
hello from B
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Barry I think the purpose of this site is to answer questions *and* to educate. The fact is that polymorphism can be compatible with vector containment if done safely. This is one of the ways to do it safely. The answer is in the vein of education.